# Teradata/SQL - returning entire rows based on duplicate column values

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata

I've been at this for hours and haven't been able to figure out a solution. I'm looking to retrieve entire rows only from unique users that share the same address (so just returning entire rows for duplicate values from the "Address" column). I've tried using a bunch of different subqueries but keep getting errors. Below is the code I've been using to get the previous day's data (this has ran fine for me so far):

```
SELECT
pl.Login_Name_Txt,
pl.Last_Name_Txt || ', ' || dp.First_Name_Txt AS User_Full_Name,
mul.Single_Factor AS Factor,
ca.City_Txt AS City,
ca.State_Txt AS State,
ca.Zip_Txt AS Zip,
ca.Address_Txt AS Address,
firstlast.Last_Played,
firstlast.First_Played, 
SUM(ps.Qty) AS Quantity,
SUM(ps.Dollars) AS Earnings

FROM Player pl

LEFT JOIN Contact_Address ca ON ca.Player_Id = pl.Player_Id
LEFT JOIN Multiplier mul ON mul.Player_Id = pl.Player_Id
LEFT JOIN First_Last firstlast ON firstlast.Player_Id = pl.Player_Id
LEFT JOIN Player_Summary ps ON ps.Player_Id = pl.Player_Id

WHERE >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
ORDER BY Address_Txt ASC
```

Comment: Hard to tell without sample data, but it's probably baased on a *Windowed Aggregate* like `qualify count(*) over (partition by Address) > 1`

Comment: I won’t be at my computer until tomorrow but I’ll give that a shot and let you know what I figure out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just tried it and I think it worked. Thank you so much @dnoeth!! You just saved me so much time.